# Erro ao conectar Flyway em aplicação spring

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, spring, flyway

**Configuração do POM:**

[image: pom.xml]

**Application.properties:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Erro ao executar projeto:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> 2019-12-19 11:23:27.844 ERROR 22884 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: **Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource**
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at com.algaworks.wine.WineApplication.main(WineApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>   Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
>       at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:56) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
>       at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1385) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
>       at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.migrate(Flyway.java:1006) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayMigrationInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(FlywayMigrationInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar:1.3.6.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar:4.2.7.RELEASE]
>       ... 23 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2330) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:806) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_232]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:710) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:644) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:466) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:143) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar:na]
>       at org.flywaydb.core.internal.util.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50) ~[flyway-core-3.2.1.jar:na]
>       ... 28 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1865) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1228) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]
>       ... 48 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1):

Este é um bug (mencionado [aqui](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/1864) e [aqui](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86221)) já conhecido para a versão `5.1.39` do driver do MySQL.

Atualize seu driver do MySQL para a versão `5.1.41` conforme recomendado no bug, esta versão possui a correção para este problema.

Para complementar, o problema pode ser identificado por esta parte da stacktrace:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null 
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39] 
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39] 
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1865) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39] 
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1228) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39] 
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39] 
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar:5.1.39]